# Creating dot-function for android calculator

Tags: java, android, xml, calculator

Im doing a small project, gathering some random calculator codes from the net and improving them to learn java and android development...

So, Im currently trying to implement a dot-function for this calculator code, but it doesn't work as it's supposed to. Instead of adding a dot, it adds the value 46 (why 46??). Could you help me to create a functional dot-function?

Java code:

```
package com.example.Elof_Calculator;



  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   public String str ="";
   Character op = 'q';
   double i,num,numtemp;
      EditText showResult;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    showResult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result_id);


   }
  public void btn1Clicked(View v){
   insert(1);

  }

   public void btn2Clicked(View v){
   insert(2);

  }
  public void btn3Clicked(View v){
   insert(3);

  }
  public void btn4Clicked(View v){
   insert(4);

  }
  public void btn5Clicked(View v){
   insert(5);

  }
  public void btn6Clicked(View v){
   insert(6);
  }
  public void btn7Clicked(View v){
   insert(7);

  }
  public void btn8Clicked(View v){
   insert(8);

  }
  public void btn9Clicked(View v){
   insert(9);

  }
  public void btn0Clicked(View v){
      insert(0);

     }
  public void btndotClicked(View v){
      insert('.');
      //error

     }
  public void btnplusClicked(View v){
   perform();
   op = '+';

  }

   public void btnminusClicked(View v){
      perform();
     op = '-';

  }
  public void btndivideClicked(View v){
   perform();
   op = '/';

  }
  public void btnmultiClicked(View v){
   perform();
   op = '*';

  }
  public void btnequalClicked(View v){
   calculate();

  }

   public void btnclearClicked(View v){
   reset();
  }
  private void reset() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  str ="";
  op ='q';
  num = 0;
  numtemp = 0;
  showResult.setText("");
  }
 private void insert(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   str = str+Integer.toString(j);
   num = Integer.valueOf(str).intValue();
   showResult.setText(str);


  }
     private void perform() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    str = "";
    numtemp = num;
     }
      private void calculate() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(op == '+')
    num = numtemp+num;
   else if(op == '-')
    num = numtemp-num;
   else if(op == '/')
    num = numtemp/num;
   else if(op == '*')
    num = numtemp*num;
   showResult.setText(""+num);
     }

    }
```

XML code for the dot-button:

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/Btndot_id"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="."
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp" 
             android:onClick="btndotClicked"
            />
```

Here is the java function and code for the dot-function specifically, which is the main error:

```
 public void btndotClicked(View v){
      insert('.');


     }
```

So, how should the code for the dot-function be?
All help is appreciated :))

Comment: Hint: 46 is the ascii value for the character '.' :)

Comment: @matiash ohh I see haha :)) I tried with insert(.), insert("."), str += "." and some other, but none worked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your insert function has the signature `void insert(int j)`

In Java an implicit widening conversion will take place, if you use a `char` primitive type when an `int` type is expected. So for example this is valid Java:

```
int dot = '.';
```

However, the value of the `int` variable `dot` will now be 46 which happens to be the integer that corresponds to the bit pattern that is used to represent `'.'`.

What you can do, is change your `insert` function to accept `String` parameters and add an overload for `int` parameters. You will also need to change your logic around `num` since you can now have floating point numbers.

```
private void insert(int value) {
    insert(Integer.toString(value));
    ...
    num = Double.parseDouble(str);
}

private void insert(String value) {        
    ...
}

...

public void btndotClicked(View v){
    insert("."); // inserting a String instead of a char
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it works much better now! :D however, when I tried for example 6.6 * 6, the result became 39,5999999994 instead of just 39.6   Why? :/  With some values it doesn't do that (e.g. 2.4*2 = 4.8)

Comment: @Chewie This is because some floating point values can only be represented approximately in a 64 bit double. It's unfortunate and a source of a lot of confusion. Have a look at this article http://floating-point-gui.de/